# Как связать автоматизацию на питоне с ConfigParser

Tags: python, selenium, ini

Для кода автоматизации ---->

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from configparser import ConfigParser

class SBMS_start():
    def open(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe')
        self.browser.get('ссылка на сайт')
        self.browser.maximize_window()

    def conf(self):
        file = 'conf.ini'
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read(file)
        self.login = config['SBMS_AUTHORISATION']['username']  #оба передаюсся в auth для вставки
        self.password = config['SBMS_AUTHORISATION']['parol']

    def auth(self):
        browser = self.browser
        sleep(1)
        login = browser.find_element_by_name("user")
        login.send_keys(login)     #LOGIN
        sleep(1)
        password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.send_keys(password)       #PASSWORD
        sleep(1)
        sign_in_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div[5]/button')#кнопка входа
        sign_in_button.click() 

class start():
    def step_on():
        work = SBMS_start()
        work.open()
        work.conf()
        work.auth()
        sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start.step_on()
```

создал файл с данными записанными в **config.ini**

```
[SBMS_AUTHORISATION]
username = test_123456
parol = test12345
```

Но данные из .ini не передаются в код. Где я мог допустить ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что посылаешь елемент пароль в самого себя:

```
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys(password)       #PASSWORD
```

нужно

```
password.send_keys(self.password)
```

Comment: капец я проморгал. Спасибо